# What's the difference between CANoe and ECU-Test

Tags: testing, canoe

With CANoe we can see the different frames, but with the ECU-Test we can see just the signals.

So i want to know the different between both tools, and why and when we can use the CANoe and ECU-Test

The difference between ecu test and caneo